# How to check if a user is signing in for the first time with Firebase Authentification

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Database, and Firebase Authentication, allowing user to sign in with Email/password or Google Sign-in. In the login activity I am trying to check if the user signing in with Google, is doing it for the first time or no.

If it is the first time that he is signing a dialog box shows up and requests the user's age and gender; if not the dialog box shouldn't appear.

The problem I am having is that the Dialog box always appears if the user signs in with Google, regardless if it is the first time or not.

Here is my code where I am trying to check if the user is signing in for the first time:

```
   protected void updateActivity(FirebaseUser user) {
    Log.d(TAG ,"updateActivity(FirebaseUser) - Ini");

    final boolean[] exist = {false};

    if(user != null) {
        ArrayList<String> providers = (ArrayList<String>) user.getProviders();
       if(!providers.isEmpty() && providers.get(0).equals("google.com")) {
           username = user.getEmail().substring(0,user.getEmail().indexOf('@'));
           String userId = user.getUid();

           Query query = mRef.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(username);

           query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot userSnapShot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                       if (!userSnapShot.getKey().equals(null) && !userSnapShot.getKey().isEmpty()) {
                           exist[0] = true;
                           Intent i  =  new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                           startActivity(i);
                           finish();

                       }
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });



       }

      if(providers.get(0).equals("password")) {
            Intent i  =  new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        showDialog();

    }



    Log.d(TAG ,"updateActivity(FirebaseUser) - Fi");

}
```

the showDialog method:

```
  public void showDialog() {

    android.app.FragmentManager fm =  getFragmentManager();
     DialogBox myDialog =  new DialogBox();
     myDialog.show(fm,"MyDialog");
}
```

As you see I have a boolean variable "exist" that it is supposed to be true if the userSnapshot has username like the user signed-in's username, in this case the dialog box should not appear.

If the "exist" value is false the dialog box should appear.

When the user is signing for the first time I have no problem, my problem is when the user had already signed in, and he is doing it again.

I don't know why

this fragment of code:

```
 query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot userSnapShot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                       if (!userSnapShot.getKey().equals(null) && !userSnapShot.getKey().isEmpty()) {
                           exist[0] = true;
                           Intent i  =  new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                           startActivity(i);
                           finish();

                       }
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });



       }
```

is executed twice and even if the user who is signing in had already signed in before, and his username exists in the database, the dialog box shows up for 1 second, and then the other activity (HomeActivity) is started.

This is my Users database in Firebase:

[image]

So, any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: In other words do you see aPt in the debug list what is aPt ???

Comment: OK, I edited my question.