# How to know if user is signing up or signing in with Facebook & Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am finding it difficult to separate sign-in logic from sign-up logic because firebase only has one method to authenticate users through Facebook: `signIn(with: AuthCredential)`. This one method will either sign-in an existing user, or register them automatically if they don't already exist, so there is no way for me to know that a user is signing up for the first time so i can persist additional info about user in firebase database.

Any help to solve this issue is greatly appreciated. My app is written in Swift so any solution with code would be most helpful in Swift. Thanks

**See comments inside callback**

```
private func rx_firebaseLogin(with credential: AuthCredential, userInfo: [String: AnyObject]) -> Observable<[String: AnyObject]> {

    return Observable<[String: AnyObject]>.create { observable in

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in

            // IF user is already authenticated, User will get signed in automatically. 
            // IF user is new, that user will automatically get signed up. 
            // So I cannot put code here to save user info in db because I could potentially just be signing in a user, and end up duplicating a pre-existing user.

            guard error == nil else {
                observable.onError(AuthError.custom(message: error!.localizedDescription))
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard user != nil else {
                observable.onError(AuthError.invalidFirebaseUser)
                print("debugger: error logging user")
                return
            }

            var data = userInfo
            data[Constant.id] = user!.uid as AnyObject

            observable.onNext(data)
            observable.onCompleted()
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference in behavior for your app between signing up for the first time and subsequently signing in? For OAuth (which is what Firebase+Facebook use here under the hood), there is no difference between these situations: it is just a user authenticating.

Comment: Wouldn't you just check to see if the authenticated user has the additional information and persist it if it is missing?

Comment: Ive added code with a few comments that hopefully clarify the problem. Paulw11, Are you suggesting that I check if authenticated user already exists in db by looking up all users and check for equality by `unique identifier` perhaps?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564918/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-signing-in-for-the-first-time-with-firebase-authentifi) is a very similar question that never got answered.

Comment: I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184770/handing-firebase-facebook-login-process?rq=1)

Comment: You shouldn't have to look up all users; surely the additional information is going to be associated with this user; try and read that information. If it is missing add it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Firebase's Database, I assume you are storing information about that user in there. When you authorize a user, check to see if that user is in your database. If they aren't, it is the first time they are signing up. Here is what I do:

```
let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current()
guard let accessTokenString = accessToken?.tokenString else {return}

let credentials = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessTokenString)

Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
    let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")

    ref.child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            //User is signing IN
        } else {
            //User is signing UP
        }
    } 
}
```

Assumed database structure:

- users

  - uniqueUserId